# Automatically call visual studio 2008 "sort using directives" on save?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-formatting, using-directives

Visual Studio 2008 got two great features for c#, which is called "sort using directives" and "remove unused using directives".

I'd like to call the "sort using directives" every time I format the code using ctrl+k,ctrl+d.

Or, even better, I would like to be able to reformat all c#-source files in a project, and call "sort using directives" for all source files.

How can I do this? Opening every cs-file by hand and typing these functions before every checkin is tedious!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it all for a solution or project using ["PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands). After installation, you just need to right-click on a project or solution and "Remove and Sort Usings" is in the context menu.

EDIT: As noted in comments, there are also [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99).

Comment: Yeah, cool. It even can reformat and sort using on file save.
Just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: After using the PowerCommands for some days, I find them lacking in one detail: There is no way to just sort usings on save. Sort & remove unused has its problems: Errors on auto-save due to build ("build in progress, can't remove unused"), errors when code does not compile.
Sort only would be nice

Comment: By the way, there are [PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99) now

Comment: Is there a way to sort usings without removing them?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496), a free and open source Visual Studio extension.  It allows you to sort usings, remove usings, format document, remove/insert blank lines, remove whitespace, and quite a few more cleanups.  It can run on save, solution wide, etc.  Follow the link to the visual studio gallery to see more details.

It also lets you conditionally enable/disable individual portions, so with it you can disable remove unused usings and do sort only if you want as you mentioned in the comments.

Disclaimer: I wrote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper can do this for you (among other reformatting options) and it allows you to do an entire solution in one go.

Comment: It would be nice if you could also say how to do this :). For the less initiated .

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you record a macro of you invoking the feature manually.  Then you can just save the macro and put a button for it on the toolbar.  This way you'll also have a foot in the door to get started really customizing your IDE.